# Cannot Delete SSRS Keys

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I need to delete and re-create the SSRS keys.

When attempting to do so via the Configuration manager I get this error

Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.DeleteEncryptedInformation()
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.DeleteEncryptedInformation()

When attempting do delete via command line

rskeymgmt.exe -d -i MSSQLSERVER

I get an Access is denied error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running with elevated permissions?

Comment: Yes, just done that thanks. Still get the Value cannot be null Parameter name Key.

Comment: Does this help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/553e5eae-1fd8-4781-93ea-10617c1eb546/wmiproviderexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-key?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thats the only page on the web I can see with any relevant info. Does not help me as yet. Still working through it.

Comment: Did you try it with only -d

Comment: As a last resort, you may want to try deleting the row manually from the `ReportServer` database. Key data is stored in `[dbo].[Keys]` table. Take and validate a backup before you decide to attempt. Since you've already decided to delete the key, I'm assuming you know that the data source connection strings and credentials will need to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You should try right click on 'cmd', 'Run as administrator'. Opening the console, run the same command you tried.